# How to find out oracle local sessions

Tags: oracle, session, connection, local

If there are any methods to find out the sessions from local machine in Oracle ?

I found that there is a 'PORT' field in v$session for V11.2.0, when we access oracle 11.2.0 on the local machine with sqlplus, the port field is 0, instead when we access oracle 11.2.0 from remote machine with sql developer, the PORT field is remote tcp port.

So we can identify the local sessions by the PORT field except the local connections via tcp with 127.0.0.1.

But another problem is that the oracle version before 11.2.0 don't have the v$session.PORT column.

Thanks

Comment: `v$session` has a `machine`column; isn't that enough?

Comment: you can join v$session and v$instance like this: select s.machine,s.username,s.sid,s.serial# from v$session s,v$instance i where s.machine=i.host_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MACHINE, TERMINAL, and PROGRAM columns.

MACHINE will match name of local host.

TERMINAL will be something like pts/1 or the Windows Machine name.

PROGRAM will be something like sqlplus@(TNS V1-V3)<--this is important because you'll also see the various internal stuff like (J001)(W001) etc. You can use a WHERE USERNAME IS NOT NULL to eliminate these unless you are looking to list all local connections.

Hope this is a good start.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is exactly what I want, though MACHINE might be unreliable, because clients can send a fake host name.